# React: e.target.? logs undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

I am trying to `setState` to `q.content`. However, it logs as undefined and I'm not sure how I'm using e.target incorrectly. It logs `q.name` fine.

I have a button that onClick calls a function that sets the constants.

In the function I have:

```js
  function handleDelete(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setDeleteItem(e.target.value);
    setConfirmModal(true);
    setDeleteContent(e.target.content);
    setDeleteName(e.target.name);
    console.log(e.target.content);
  }
```

```html
<button
   onClick={handleDelete}
   value={q.id}
   name={q.name}
   content={q.content}
   >
```

But it just doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Not all attributes are available as DOM properties. While you can call `e.target.value`, you cannot call `e.target.content` in like manner. Instead, you'll need to access the element's *attributes* to get that value. To do so, check the [`e.target.attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes) object, or use [`e.target.getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute).

Answer (score 0):

Try this to pass attribute value to the function:

```
function handleDelete(e) {
    console.log(e.target.getAttribute('content')) //'CONTENT!"
    setContent(e.target.getAttribute('content')) //set as state
}

<button
    onClick={handleDelete}
    content={'CONTENT!'}
></button>
```